# Websockets: Meaning of named server?

Tags: websocket

A typical example explaining how to use websockets can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications.

From that page:

> This simple example creates a new WebSocket, connecting to the server
>   at http://www.example.com/socketserver. It specifies a protocol of
>   "my-custom-protocol".
>
> var mySocket = new WebSocket("http://www.example.com/socketserver",
>   "my-custom-protocol");

My question has to do with "socketserver" in this example of the websocket server address. A socket server is going to be listening on a port, right? So, I can understand something like this:

```
var mySocket = new WebSocket("http://www.example.com:4242", "my-custom-protocol");
```

That would be like any old way of making a connection to a socket server, like `myGuy.connect(4242);`.

What type of connection is the browser using for initial access to "socketserver" above when a port number is not given? URLConnection? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning of the Websocket protocol is like HTTP.  If a port is not specified in the URL, the default port of 80 is used.  A connection is established using TCP/IP.  The initial bytes sent by the client will include the path `/socketserver` in them, so that's how the host knows what the client is requesting.

Wikipedia has an example of the opening communication between a websocket client and a websocket server that you should look at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_Protocol_Handshake

Comment: I'd seen that information before, but I think somehow the "GET /demo HTTP/1.1" flashed right past my eyes ... maybe I was looking at the other part. It's a GET request, right? So, the example they give could be processed by the doGet() on a Servlet?

Comment: It looks like a GET request at first, that's most the I can say.  Also I don't know what a servlet is.

Comment: Time has passed. I know more about it now than I used to. Just thought I'd get back .... yep ... it comes in as an http request. The request is to upgrade to a websocket. I can now add that HttpExchange will then fail because it closes the connection after responding (promising that it will upgrade the connection).

Comment: Did I succeed in answering your original question, which was "What type of connection is the browser using for initial access to 'socketserver' above when a port number is not given?"

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I've made a lot of progress on this since then.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets establish a connection via an HTTP Upgrade request. So in the case above, the Web Server will re-route the Upgrade Request on `/socketserver` to the actual webs ocket server which then handles the connection via the WS protocol.

Comment: Is the reference to /socketserver similar to the url reference in an AJAX request? As, for example;  url = "validate2";

 req.onreadystatechange = callback;
 req.open("POST", url, true);